# Not able to get hidden field value from `jsp` to `spring mvc controller`

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I testing my payment related code with hidden amount value that I will receive from user but I am not able to get `<form:hidden>` fields value to my action controller.
I am able to get rest other fields but not getting hidden field.

**JSP form**

```
 <form:form id="frmCard" method="post" action="${payment_url}"
    align="center" modelAttribute="payment">
    <div id="my-card" class="card-js"  data-capture-name="true"
        data-icon-colour="#337ab7">

    <form:input path="card_number" class="card-number" placeholder="Card Number" />
    <form:input path="card_name" class="name englishonly" placeholder="Name On Card" maxlength="21" />
    <form:input path="card_expiry_month" class="expiry-month" />
    <form:input path="card_expiry_year" class="expiry-year" />
    <form:input path="card_cvc" class="cvc" />
            
    <form:hidden path="amount" value="10" /> <-------------------THIS Field
    <p>
        <div>
            <img src="../img/cards.png">
        </div>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Pay" />
</form:form>
```

**Controller method**

```
@PostMapping("/addPayment")
public String payment(@ModelAttribute("payment") Payment payment ) {
    System.out.println(""+payment.getCard_number()); // getting value
    System.out.println("$ "+payment.getAmount()); // not getting value
    String status = "error";
    try {
        status = paymentService.process(payment);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

how do I make this work.

***edit***

If I mark fields `readonly` instead of `<form:hidden>` then there is no problem and I am getting all fields. Why am I not getting values from hidden fields then in my controller. Can someone explain..

Comment: Setting `value` when using `form:path` won't work. As the value from `payment.getAmount` will override the `value` set.  If you want to set a default you have to set that in the controller in the GET request when constructing the object. If you check the HTML that is generated you will see that the `value` for the hidden field is something else then 10.

Comment: I was following this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_hidden.htm

Comment: and how come I am able to get card_number value in controller from same jsp, when it is not hidden.

Comment: instead of hidden if I mark the field readonly, I am getting all values. Why is it not possible for hidden fields then?

Comment: That does not have a `value` set in the JSP, that gets the value that has been set in the controller on your `Payment`. Making it a regular input instead of using `form:hidden` bypasses the fact that spring uses `paymet.getAmount()` to determine the initial value to set on the field.

Comment: ok. Will this work - `<input type="text" name="amount" hidden="true" value="10">`

Comment: Yes as that as well bypassed springs form tags, but as stated ifyou want a default just set it in the controller where you prepare the `Payment` in the `@GetMapping` probably.

Comment: Does your `Payment` class have an attribute of `amount` with relevant getter and setter methods?

Comment: finally I had to use inline css style `display:none`. very strange issue with spring mvc. hidden should be treated invisible to UI but it definitely should wire with controller model attribute